# Getting "Missing Security Answer" when changing Game Centre nickname

Tags: apple-id, game-center

When I go into settings>gamecentre>profile to change my nickname, a box pops up when I click Done saying, "Missing Security Answer Please enter the answer to your security question." 
I've tried everything from logging into my apple ID and changing the security question and answer to restarting the ipod. I'm not sure what's going on or how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's troubleshooting article has details on how to proceed with troubleshooting Game Center.

- http://support.apple.com/en-us/TS3970

Why not start there and ask a second, more detailed question if one of the steps has you confused or stuck. Without more details edited in to your question, it's hard to guess where you are stuck in the process.

It might be as simple as you following the steps above and then entering the correct "answer" to your changed security question from https://appleid.apple.com

Comment: I have done all of apples troubleshooting for it. When I am trying to change the nickname of the game centre profile, a box pops up saying "missing security answer" when it isn't. I have changed the security question, shut down the ipod and restarted, changed the question and answer using a pc, tried on a different ipod, on an iphone etc.. It all comes up saying "missing security answer"! I can't figure it out! Our other game centre profiles change with no dramas.

Comment: @Jenn "All of Apple's troubleshooting" is a big amount of steps. It usually ends with "contact support" if these steps don't resolve it. Can you sign in and out on that Apple ID?